How to import a 3d model in my Android app
How to add a 3d model in my Android app. Maybe this has an obvious answer but I am new to the field of Android development and didn't find any proper editorial online. I am working with Compose UI with Kotlin. I have one view in the screen where I want to display a 3d model in upper view and it's description in bottom view of my mobile screen. Like below...
enter image description here
So, can anyone guide me how to achieve this with 3D models already downloaded in my mobile.
Can anyone guide me how to achieve 2 views like this with 3D models already downloaded in my mobile.

https://github.com/manjeetdeswal/3d-Model-Rendering-Filament-

https://kashif-mehmood-km.medium.com/display-3d-models-in-sceneview-using-arcore-and-sceneform-in-your-android-app-2e92f4cdeed6

https://github.com/SceneView/sceneview-android
